# ansible-core requires a minimum of Python2 version 2.7

Tags: python

I have an ansible playbook that updates an HTML file from local (on a Mac Mini) to an apache server.   When I run it, I get ..

```
fatal: [www.invalid.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/var/www/html/travels/index.html): ansible-core requires a minimum of Python2 version 2.7 or Python3 version 3.5. Current version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]"}
```

But ..

```
python -V
Python 3.10.6
```

So, ansible is not using the correct version of the interpreter.

This is on MacOS Monterey, and there is no ansible.cfg under /etc.

Can someone tell me how to get ansible using the correct version?

Thank you.

Comment: Apple doesn't ship a python 2.6 on Monterey, where did you install it from?.

Comment: `Current version: 2.6.6 ... (Red Hat` probably means the "apache server" is RedHat Linux with a somewhat old version of Python. So you'll probably want to update the remote server.